# Is the environment in a video game part of the narrative?

Tags: creative-writing, narrative, videogame

Is the environment in a video game part of the narrative? The Elden Ring won the award for the best narrative in the Game Awards Show, and some people were outraged, because most of the storytelling in that game is done through item description and what the game environment tells you, so I was wondering if the environment is part of the narrative and why. I am asking, because the environment is art, it's an image, and the formal description seems to imply it needs to be said or written.

> 3. to relate or recount events, experiences, etc., in speech or writing.

Comment: Is that quote labeled "3" part of a definition of narrative? Actually, I'm fairly sure it isn't but it might be a definition of "narrate". Have you looked in other sources? For instance one dictionary gives as one of its definitions of [narrative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrative) "the representation in art of an event or story". It seems like you're deliberately picking a definition to prove Elden Ring didn't deserve a prize. (Also you should say where the thing you are quoting is from, or provide a link.)

Answer (score 3):

Games are not just literature. They have a lot more tools at their disposal than just words to get the narrative across.

One important buzzword in the game industry is "environmental storytelling". Telling stories not by having the player read or listen to them, but by letting the player know that a certain story happened or is happening by having them observe and interact with the game environment. This alone can be used to make the player experience powerful narratives.

Let's take just this screenshot from Fallout 4, for example:
[image]

What does the player see here? What's already established is that the game takes place after a nuclear war. The person who used to be this skeleton had a dufflebag packed. So he was obviously prepared to leave his home in case of the apocalypse. But he didn't. Instead, he died sitting on the couch in a relaxed pose with a bottle of in his hand. Why? Perhaps because although he had prepared, when the apocalypse actually happened, he changed his mind and decided that he would rather want to drink himself to death in the comfort of his own home rather than experience the hardship of wandering through a nuclear wasteland.

Or maybe you see something else in this scene? That's one of the hallmarks of good art: It allows multiple interpretations.

But environmental storytelling is a device that can be used in any visual medium, not just games. Games have another narrative tool at their disposal that is unique to the medium: **Telling stories through game mechanics**. But this is an entirely different subject which the question didn't ask about.